# Method called when new activity starts

Tags: java, android

When I start a new android activity the methods that are being called before the activity actually appears in the screen are `onCreate()` -> `onStart()` -> `onResume()`? or there are some more called before I see the activity on the screen?

I've written an application in which I overrode only the `onCreate()` method from the three I mentioned before, but from some reason the application crashes, although the `onCreate()` finishes successfuly.

onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("SMARTGAN", "starting ChildActivity onCreate()");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);

    // find child for the activity
    child = (Child) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.CHILD);

    // initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), child);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // set action bar properties
    actionBar.setTitle(child.getName());
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_person);

    // adding the tabs to the action bar
    for (int i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i])
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    // set OnPageChangeListener so that whenever the user changes the page
    // the selected tab in the action bar also changes
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }
    });
    Log.d("SMARTGAN", "ChildActivity onCreate completed");
}
```

Comment: Post your code and the stacktrace. This may be helpful too : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: Post your logcat output

Comment: How can I get the stacktrace?

Comment: Either share your code or your logcat output or both.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find your answer in this android activity lifecycle

[image: android activity lifecycle]

Comment: It makes no sense, why does my application crash if the onCreate has finished and I haven't override onStart and OnResume? I cant even find where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your activity to the AndroidManifest.xml file? The second way: maybe you have problem with you content view (when setting view with setContentView() method)?

Comment: The setContentView has finish long before the application crashed